# What settings should I use to shoot an event (greyhound protest)?

Tags: camera-settings, event-photography

I have a Nikon D3100. I'm attending a greyhound protest soon and I need help with the settings, such as ISO, aperture, and focus mode, etc. There will be a lot of people and dogs there, moving about. I prefer not to take photos using auto!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What settings to use, as in aperture, IOS, focus mode, ect...

Comment: What lens do you have? Are you taking pictures from far away, or will you be very close to the subjects? Why do you prefer not to use auto mode? What is your level of familiarity with your camera, its exposure modes, its focusing modes? Have you read the camera's manual?

Comment: What time of day.  Daytime or night/dusk?  This is an important consideration.

Answer (score 3):

> I prefer not to take photos using auto!

I understand this preference, but I think if your goal is to record this event, you *should* use auto. That's because the question itself indicates that you are uncomfortable with the basic exposure parameters and their use. Auto will take care of this for you — maybe not with the best possible results, but certainly with better results than using manual mode without understanding.

It's good to increase understanding by experimenting and learning, but an event you want to photograph probably isn't the time to do that, unless your goal is primarily learning and getting good results a possible nice side effect.

There are lots of valid possibilities for all of the parameters you mention; it all depends on what you want. Auto mode will generally get you acceptable middling-conservative results. Once you understand what you want *different* from that, it's time to dig into manual control.